# create a bat file to run 3 programs in order

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, startup

Hello i have 3 programs that i run every day one by one i would like to create a bat file the run this 3 exe file but i can't make it work.

here my file:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo "start audio"

start "C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-Audio2\ProsimAudio.v2.exe"

timeout /t 5 > nul

start "C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimIOS\ProSimIOS.exe"

timeout /t 5 > nul

start "C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-System\ProSimA322-System.exe"

echo "done"
```

but nothing start
any idea what im doing wrong

Comment: Because your executables are doublequoted, you need a title. You can even have an empty one, so change `start` to `start ""`.

Comment: Type `start /?` and hit Enter from a command prompt, and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally understood the one comment on this question meant after typing a whole answer. But I'll keep that answer up anyways and have this as a separate one.

**Considering it wasn't immediately clear to me what was meant, I'll add one of the three lines of code:**

BEFORE (original not working code)

```
start "C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-Audio2\ProsimAudio.v2.exe"
```

AFTER (new working code)

```
start "" "C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-Audio2\ProsimAudio.v2.exe"
```

Make sure to add the `""` after the `start` to all three `start` commands, not just the one.

Answer (score 0):

The `""` markings are considered a switch for the title of a new cmd window.** All that your code starts is three new cmd windows, with the
titles of the file paths you're trying to open.

As you do not have spaces in your file path, you can simply get rid of the `""`, but if you had spaces you would have to do the other method of starting a file which is to just type its name (without the `start` command before it). This has to be done with `""` around it if there are spaces, but it doesn't matter if you have them or not when there are no spaces. Simply typing the file's name is not enough if it's not in the same directory as the current directory of the batch script, so you would need to change the directory using `cd`. Using a file's name instead of `start` will run it within the command prompt window if it can be run through it, though. But that's not a thing for most executable files.

I gave some unnecessary information above, but it may be useful to you anyways.

The code below has a few more things added to it for better ease of
use, but you can always go back to your original code. The only change
needed to make your code work was to remove the `""` in the parameter
for the `start` command.

```
@echo off
title Start Audio
echo.
echo -Start Audio-
echo.
echo Press any key to begin . . . 
pause >nul
start C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-Audio2\ProsimAudio.v2.exe
echo.
echo Started ProsimAudio.v2.exe
pause
start C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimIOS\ProSimIOS.exe
echo Started ProSimIOS.exe
pause
start C:\Users\damia\Desktop\A320\ProSimA322-System\ProSimA322-System.exe
echo Started ProSimA322-System.exe
echo.
echo Done.
echo Press any key to exit . . . 
pause >nul
exit
```